# Javascript: variable file from string

Tags: javascript

Hopefully this is a pretty simple question for those who know javascript but I couldn't figure it out.  Basically I have a save file dialog box created with this:

```
<div>
<input type="file" id="file" onchange="loadFile(this)">
</div>
```

It is linked to the "loadfile" function shown below:

```
function loadFile(input) {
  var file = input.files[0]
  var url = file.urn || file.name;

  ID3.loadTags(url, function() {showTags(url);}, {tags: ["title","artist","album","picture"],dataReader: FileAPIReader(file)});
}
```

I am trying to replace the line

```
 var file = input.files[0]
```

to be a file from a string (specified path) instead of relying on the file browser dialog. I have tried something like this:

```
 var file = files("song.mp3")
```

but the resulting function will not work. I am guessing that my variable file isn't of the right type. How do I get it to be the same type as the selected file from the file dialog box?

Thanks in advance!

PS:
I am trying to link my script to a path on the server not the client.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access data from a website, then use the `XMLHttpRequest` object instead of the Files API.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion but I am trying to link my script to a file on the server not the client. I know this will most likely need to be done with some php but am unsure how to.

Comment: So var file = XMLHttpRequest("song.mp3") ?

Comment: Err… no, but there are [many guides to XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest) so I'm not going to write another one here.